# Linux Bash kill consecutive processes

Tags: bash, kill

I wrote a sequence of process in bash like

```
#!/bin/bash
#sample.sh
for filename in ./*
do
./a.out filename
done
```

then I run the script with the nohup command:

```
nohup sh sample.sh 2>&1 &
```

then I discovered that something went wrong with a.out. I was trying modify the a.out and first I need to **kill** the processes, but it turned out that I can only kill one at a time. There are hundreds of files in `./*` directory.

How to kill them all with one or a few commands?

Comment: `./a.out` does not matter since you are not running it on the background, the only process you are running on the background is `sample.sh` , killing it , stops the entire process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pid is printed when the `nohup` command is executed. Use it with kill like this:

```
$ nohup sh sample.sh 2>&1 &
[1] 25062
appending output to nohup.out
$kill 25062
[1]+  Terminated: 15          nohup sh sample.sh 2>&1
```

Or if you don't have the pid, you can use `ps -ef | grep sample` to find it. Then, use the pid to kill the process. Like this:

```
$ nohup sh sample.sh 2>&1 &
[1] 25066
appending output to nohup.out
$ ps -ef | grep sample
  501 25066  2768   0 10:48PM ttys001    0:00.01 sh sample.sh
  501 25070  2768   0 10:49PM ttys001    0:00.01 grep sample
$ kill 25066
[1]+  Terminated: 15          nohup sh sample.sh 2>&1
$
```